# rails selectbox_tag onchange()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say we have a select box: 
/app/views/tape/_form.html.erb 
`<%= f.select :tape, Tape::LIST_TAPES %>`

and a *.js.coffee* file that i would like to trigger when some value is selected in selectbox:
/app/assets/javascripts/tapes.js.coffee

```
function selectBoxValue(value){
  # value -- selected in selectbox;
  console.log("box_value = ", value);
}
```

How can it be done in RoR 3.2?
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/7q2s9/7/) what i mean within html+js.

**P.S.**
I'm new to Rails. Sorry for my English and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
<%= f.select :tape, Tape::LIST_TAPES, :id => 'some_id' %>
```

js file:

```
$(function(){
    $('#some_id').change(function(){ 
        selectBoxValue(this.value); 
    });
});
```

Pay attention that your select tag already has `id` so you can use it and remove `:id => 'some_id'`

Comment: Can see in your post now. I've put it in my `/app/assets/javascripts/tapes.js.coffee` and caugth an error in this line: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. P.S. gem 'jquery-rails' is installed.

Comment: It is because you are using a coffee script. You can rename tapes.js.coffee to tapes.js

Comment: Emm... sorry, is that jquery script correct? I got: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` in third line;